# inorder traversal returns only one value

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, recursive-datastructures

I have written the program to convert a sorted array into a bst but when I run inorder on it it only returns one value,

```
static Node insert(int[] arr, int lo, int hi){
        if(lo>hi){
            return null;
        }
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo)/2;
        root = new Node(arr[mid]);
        root.left = insert(arr, lo, mid-1);
        root.right = insert(arr, mid+1, hi);
        return root;
    }
```

inOrder(insert(nodes, 0, nodes.length-1)); - return only 87, inorder is the regular recursive function.
the array int[] nodes = {12, 25, 37, 50, 62, 75, 87};

Answer (score 0):

```
root = new Node(arr[mid]); // wrong
```

You should declare root pointer at local scope. Currently you just modify the one declared at outer scope and end up returning that at the ending.

Change to:

```
Node root = new Node(arr[mid]);
```

Comment: got t thnx @Staz